# Jersey Test + HK2 + Inject Factory service

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, hk2, jersey-test-framework

I am trying to inject a object provided by HK2 Factory service in a Jersey Test Class but getting unsatisfied dependencies exception.

I have a factory service as below

```
    public class TestFactory implements Factory<TestObject>{

        private final CloseableService closeService;

        @Inject
        public TestFactory(CloseableService closeService) {
            this.closeService = closeService;
        }

        @Override
        public TestObject provide() {
            TestObject casualObject = new TestObject();
            this.closeService.add(() -> dispose(casualObject));
            return casualObject;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(TestObject instance) {
            instance.destroy();
        }
    }
```

And a Jersey Test class

```
    public class SampleTestCass extends JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerClassTest
    {

      //@Inject
      private TestObject myTestObject;

      private ServiceLocator locator;


     @Override
        protected Application configure()
        {
            ResourceConfig resConfig = new ResourceConfig(MyApi.class);
            resConfig.register(getBinder());
            locator = setupHK2(getBinder());

            return resConfig;
        }

        // setup local hk2
        public setupHK2(AbstractBinder binder) 
        {
            ServiceLocatorFactory factory = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance();
            ServiceLocator locator = factory.create("test-locator");

            DynamicConfigurationService dcs = locator.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class);
            DynamicConfiguration dc = dcs.createDynamicConfiguration();

            locator.inject(binder);
            binder.bind(dc);
            dc.commit();
            return locator;
        }

        // get the binder
        public AbstractBinder getBinder()
        {
        return new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    bindFactory(TestFactory.class, Singleton.class).to(TestObject.class).in(PerLookup.class);
                }

            }
        }

         @BeforeClass
        public void beforeClass()
        {
            myTestObject = locator.getService(TestObject.class);

            // use myTestObject
        }

         @AfterClass
        public void afterClass()
        {
            if (locator != null) {
                locator.shutdown();
            }
        }

        @Test()
        public void someTest()
        {
            // some test code...
        }

    }
```

And getting below exceptions

A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:

1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=CloseableService,parent=TestFactory,qualifiers={},position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2053349061)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.test.factories.TestFactory errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.test.factories.TestFactory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CloseableService` is a service available *within* a Jersey application. The `ServiceLocator` you created is *not* tied to the Jersey application. It is just a standalone locator. So trying to register the `TestFactory` with this locator will cause it to fail, as there is no `CloseableService`. The one that you registered with the `ResourceConfig` will work just fine.

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but if you want access to the service inside the test, one thing you can do is just bind the service as an instance, something like

```
class MyTest {
    private Service service;

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        service = new Service();
        return new ResourceConfig()
            .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    bind(service).to(Service.class);
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: As you've said, `CloseableService` (indirectly) created the problem when used in the test classes. It worked the way you have described. I am just trying to use the `Factory` services as used in non test classes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you're saying that you want to be able to use the TestFactory in a non-jersey test, then mock out the CloseableService and bind the mock.

Comment: I meant the way we `@Inject` in Jersey Resource classes (`@Path`)